# Is there an equivalent for toPrecision() in PHP?

Tags: php, math

For example a number to 3 significant figures would be as follows

```
12345 => 12300
0.12345 => 0.123
0.012345 => 0.0123
```

Comment: You could use `number_format` http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Round those decimals in a natural way oder just display these numbers as mentioned? The Javascript function rounds as well. See the given examples here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toprecision.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built in to round to a given number of significant figures (as opposed to a given number of digits.) Math to the rescue!

```
function toPrecision($number, $precision) {
    if ($number == 0) return 0;
    $exponent = floor(log10(abs($number)) + 1);
    $significand =
        round(
            ($number / pow(10, $exponent))
            * pow(10, $precision)
        )
        / pow(10, $precision);
    return $significand * pow(10, $exponent);
}

$numbers = [
    12345,
    .12345,
    .012345,
];

foreach($numbers as $number) {
    echo toPrecision($number, 3), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
12300
0.123
0.0123
```

Comment: all that can do the round() function. see my examples.

Answer (score 0):

In php, you could use round() function. It accepts two parameters, the number and precision, such as

```
echo round(12345, -2); # will result in 12300
echo round(0.12345, 3); # will result in 0.123
```

See the [php manual on round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) for more information.

Comment: If you read the OP - he wants to display at 3 decimal points, never was the fact mentioned about rounding up or down. So using round() will not do what he wanted. number_format() is what is needed as he wants to format numbers only

Comment: Hi Steve. As mentioned in a comment above, the javascript function toPrecision() rounds as well. See the examples at MDN: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toprecision.asp

Comment: This wouldn't work correctly for 0.012345, using round() will end up with 0.012 rather than 0.0123 which is three significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

There are several functions you can use for math operations. Here are a few examples

```
// 0.12345 => 0.123 - round half down
$result = round(0.12345, 3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)

// 0.12345 => 0.124 - natural rounding
$result = round(0.12345. 3);

// 12345 => 12300
$result = round(12345, -2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

The round() function rounds integers by the given precision. Please respect the natural sorting. Higher than 5 means rounding up as far as you don 't mention the PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN constant.

Comment: This wouldn't work correctly for 0.012345, using round() will end up with 0.012 rather than 0.0123 which is three significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use number_format() to achieve what you need.

```
$value = 0.12345;
$output = number_format($value, 3);
echo $output;
```

This will return: 0.123

Or you could wrap this withing a foreach loop if you need to go through an array, or alternatively create your own function to accept an integer and return the formatted value.

```
function formatNumber($int){
  $number = number_format($int, 3);
  return $number;
}
```

Or alternatively look at the link below to see if there is any other way you want to do this.

[PHP.NET PAGE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: This wouldn't work correctly for 0.012345, using round() will end up with 0.012 rather than 0.0123 which is three significant figures.